# Can't get kerkis work properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, chapters, greek

I am testing a few chapter styles to work with `kerkis` font in greek. The weird thing is that although I load the package, the fontstyle doesn't pass inside the document. My first attempt is the following

[image]

and its code is

```
%---------------- Square Box on Top Right Corner -----------------------
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\ChapWd
\settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {
    \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
      at ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-15pt]current page.north east) 
      (numb) {\thechapter};
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west) {\chaptertitlename};
    }
  }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\DoPToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
}

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}
%\selectfont{kekris}

\chapter{Title of the first chapter}
\epigraph{A brainy quote -- Its Author}{}
\DoPToC
\lipsum[4]
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Another test section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Yet another test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Title of the second chapter}
\DoPToC
\lipsum[4]
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Another test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

You can see that despite loading `kerkis`, the fonts aren't kerkis at all. The same happens with another style, as seen in the next figure

[image]

There, although `chaptername` is really in kerkis, everything else is in `babel`'s default. The code for that is

```
%------------------- Round Boxes ------------------------------
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rounded corners=30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill=myblueii,
  open rectangle sides=#1,
  }
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont#1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at (titlerect.south west) {\Huge#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}

% \setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1.5\baselineskip}
% \setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
% \setlength\epigraphwidth{6.8cm}
% \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
% \renewcommand\epigraphsize{\large}
% \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
% 
% \let\oldepigraph\epigraph \renewcommand\epigraph[2]{%
%   \oldepigraph{\color{mybluei}\itshape #1}{#2}}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}

\setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{6.8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0.1pt}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\large}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\let\oldepigraph\epigraph \renewcommand\epigraph[2]{%
  \oldepigraph{\color{blue}\itshape #1}{#2}}

% \makeatletter
% \xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
% \makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand\DoPToC{%
\startcontents\printcontents{}{1}{\noindent{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par\medskip}}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\begin{document}

\chapter{From the Ground Up!}
\epigraph{In theory there is no difference \\ between theory and practice. \\ In practice there is.}{Lawrence ``Yogui'' Berra,1925 \\ New York Yankees baseball player}
\DoPToC
\chapter*{A test unnumbered chapter}
\DoPToC
\chapter{Another chapter}
\epigraph{In theory there is no difference \\ between theory and practice. \\ In practice there is.}{Lawrence ``Yogui'' Berra,1925 \\ New York Yankees baseball player}
\DoPToC
\section{A simple section}
\section{Another simple section}

\end{document}
```

Any idea on why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken kerkis is a serif font. this means every time `\sffamily` is invoked a substitution font is used... and the greek support for this font might not be complete.

Comment: @s__C : I also removed `\ssfamily`(because it's the only font-relevant command) but I didn't see any difference...

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{fourier}`.

Comment: @egreg : Thank you very much for your comment. Removing `fourier` works for the second case but not for the first one.

Comment: @Thanos In the first code you have `\usepackage{lmodern}` after `\usepackage{kerkis}`: remove `lmodern`.

Comment: @egreg : That seemed to work it out! Thank's a lot! Would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have conflicting font packages. In the first code you have `\usepackage{lmodern}` after `\usepackage{kerkis}`, so LaTeX is instructed first to use Kerkis and then to change the font to Latin Modern.

Similarly, in the second code you have `\usepackage{fourier}`, that instructs LaTeX to use Utopia for text and Fourier form math. Remove the call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OpenType version of Kerkis (http://iris.math.aegean.gr/kerkis/) and then run `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=Kerkisbold,
             ItalicFont=Kerkisitalics]{Kerkis}
\setsansfont{KerkisSans}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength\ChapWd
\settowidth\ChapWd{\huge\chaptertitlename}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,122}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter\sffamily}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {
    \node[fill=myblue,font=\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east,minimum size=\ChapWd] 
      at ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-15pt]current page.north east) 
      (numb) {\thechapter};
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt,font=\huge] at (numb.west) {\chaptertitlename};
    }
  }{0pt}{\fontsize{33}{40}\selectfont\color{myblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{50pt}{10pt}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ttl@printlist}{\endgroup}{{\noindent\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\vskip30pt\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\DoPToC{%
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\noindent{\color{myblue}\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\par\medskip}%
}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of the first chapter}
\epigraph{Ένας έξυπνος απόσπασμα - Συγγραφέας του}{}
\DoPToC
Είμαι δοκιμές μερικές μορφές κεφαλαίου να συνεργαστεί με γραμματοσειρά Κέρκης στα ελληνικά. Το περίεργο είναι Παρόλο που δεν φορτώσει το πακέτο, το στυλ γραμματοσειράς δεν χωράει μέσα στο έγγραφο. Η πρώτη μου προσπάθεια είναι η ακόλουθη:
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I want to avoid using `XeLaTeX`. In previous tries I always had issues with the encoding or with `tikz` or `beamer` or almost everything! The same main document code, couldn't work as is when running `XeLaTeX`...

Comment: Xelatex is pure UTF8 it cannot really have problems with encodings.

Comment: You are right. I just remembered it was the editor who had the problem. I had to fix the encoding there. Nevertheless, I couldn't compile my previous `pdfLaTeX` documents even if I applied the relevant changes in the preamble...